# Salesforce search setting "Lookup Auto-Completion" not working inside jquery datatable.for page 2 and above for 1st page it's working fine

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce2salesforce

I am using  Salesforce search setting "Lookup Auto-Completion",and i am populating multiple records and for dispaly i used JQuery Datatable.Autocomplete is working for page 1 but not for rest of the pages

this is jquery:

```
<script> j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); j$(document).ready(function() { j$('[id$="tabs"]').tabs(); j$('[id$="table1"]').dataTable(); j$('[id$="table2"]').dataTable(); }); </script>
```

this is my html :

```
<table id ="table1"> <thead> <tr> <th>Financial Accounts</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <apex:repeat value="{!accts}" var="a"> <tr> <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Financial_Accounts__c}"/></td> </tr> </apex:repeat> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Without any code posted there is little anyone can comment on. And even with code this may be a combination that requires some careful JavaScript debugging to figure out and you are probably best placed to do that.

Comment: ' <script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
      j$(document).ready(function() {
            j$('[id$="tabs"]').tabs();
                 j$('[id$="table1"]').dataTable();
                 j$('[id$="table2"]').dataTable();
                 });
            </script>

Comment: ' <table id ="table1">
        <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Financial Accounts</th>
         </tr>
          </thead>
           <tbody>
          <apex:repeat value="{!accts}" var="a">
           <tr>
           <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Financial_Accounts__c}"/></td>
          </tr>
           </apex:repeat>
           </tbody>
           </table>''